# Try catch in a JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, try-catch

I'm writing unit tests for an application that already exists for a long time. Some of the methods I need to test are build like this:

```
public void someMethod() throws Exception { 
   //do something 
}
```

If I want to test these methods I have to write something like this in my unit test:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
   try {
      someMethod();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Is it a good practice to do this? Or is there an other way to test these methods?

I did some research on the internet and I found a few solutions with the `@Rule` annotation and `@Test(expected=Exception.class)`, but that's not working (Eclipse keeps showing the `someMethod()` line in the test as wrong).
I don't know if these are good solutions, because I'm pretty new to the whole unit testing story.

If someone who knows a lot about this could help me out, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Don't suppress the exception unless you want the test to pass whether or not the exception is thrown. Note that a test which passes "whether or not" something like an exception occurs may not be that useful.

Comment: You can just let take JUnit to take care of the Exception by adding it to your method sig: public void someTest() throws Exception.
However if you want to catch the Exception yourself to assert it being caugt the example you have given is good to go.

Comment: @Makoto JUnit "takes care of it" by printing the stack trace and failing the test.

Comment: @immibis:  Yes, this is true.  In convention though, declaring an exception to be thrown is letting either some higher level framework handle it or the JVM.  I should've been clearer on that point.

Comment: Whether it is a good idea depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Since `Exception` is a checked exception, you either:

- Have to catch the exception in a `try...catch` statement, or
- Declare the exception to be thrown in the method itself.

What you have up there works fine, but my personal preference is to declare the exception to be thrown.  This way, if an exception I'm not expecting is thrown during the run of the test, the test will *fail*.

```
@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    // dodgy code here
}
```

If we need to see if a specific exception is thrown, then you have the option of using `@Rule` or adding the value to the `@Test` annotation directly.

```
@Test(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    // dodgy code here
}
```

In JUnit 5, you can leverage [`Assertions.assertThrows`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-) to accomplish the same thing.  I'm less familiar with this overall since it's not yet GA at the time of editing, but it appears to accept an `Executable` coming from JUnit 5.

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    assertThrows(FileNotFoundException.class, () ->
         { dodgyService.breakableMethod() };
}
```

Comment: The fact is: I don't expect the exception to be thrown. Isn't my test going to fail if no exception is thrown?

Comment: Nope!  If no exception is thrown, then the test will pass normally provided it satisfies your other assertions.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess I didn't understood that quite well. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that just because you don't expect the exception to ever be thrown in your production system, doesn't mean it isnt a good idea to make sure that it is thrown in a test, and that the handling is sensible - is putting a note in the log, advising a user of failure etc, cleanly closing out the system, closing threads ~ you never know when a network outage will cause your file to not be found, or printer to be unavailable etc. Don't let your users PC freeze up due to a badly handled exception awaiting a thread to be released, or resource to be made available again.

Comment: "what you have up there works fine"? no way, it's intolerably awful.

Comment: The `expected` in `@Test` **is not allowed** as of JUnit 5.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal:  Given that JUnit5 is not yet GA, I was blissfully unaware of this fact.  I have revised my answer, though.

Comment: @Makoto Same, I was unaware too. I really liked the expected approach and wasted around 10 minutes to get it to work until I figured out why. Just wanted to prevent anyone else running into the same problem.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal: ...you could have just posted your own answer, y'know...

Comment: @Makoto I felt like contributing to the top voted answer since its easier to spot :)

Answer (score 28):

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
   try {
     someMethod();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
     Assert.fail("Exception " + e);
   }
}
```

Is what you can do, if the exception should not occur. An alternative would be to throw the exception in the signature like this:

```
@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
     someMethod();
}
```

The difference is, that in one case the test will fail with an assertion exception and in the other case it will fail because the test crashed. (like somewhere in your code you get a NPE and the test will because of that)

The reason you have to do this, is because Exception is a checked exception. See [Checked versus unchecked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129)

The @Test(expected=Exception.class) is for tests, that want to test that the exception will be thrown.

```
@Test(expected=ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.class)
public void testIndex() {
   int[] array = new int[0];
   int var = array[0]; //exception will be thrown here, but test will be green, because we expect this exception

}
```

Comment: This reimplements how junit would handle the exception, but worse, since you lose the stack trace, making it hard to know where that exception occurred.

Answer (score 10):

Do not catch your application's exception in your test code. Instead, declare it to be thrown upwards.

Because, when JUnit's `TestRunner` finds an exception thrown, it will automatically log it as an `error` for the testcase.

Only if you `testcase` expects that the method should thrown an `Exception` you should use `@Test(expected=Exception.class)` or catch the exception.

In other cases, just throw it upwards with,

```
public void someTest() throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add exception in test method signature. Then, if you are testing whether exception is thrown, you have to use `@Test(expected=Exception.class)`. In the test cases where exception has not to be thrown, test will pass successfully.

```
@Test
public void testCaseWhereExceptionWontBeThrown() throws Exception {
    someMethod(); //Test pass
}

@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void testCaseWhereExceptionWillBeThrown() throws Exception {
    someMethod(); //Test pass
}
```

Comment: I think some example code would help your answer, since I think he may have tried something similar already, but not got the syntax right.

Comment: For me the second code block is failing because code that I am testing has a try-catch block. I'm just trying to test whether a specific exception happens when I call using a bad-value.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main rules on how to process exceptions at Junit testers:

1. If the exception was originated into the tested code:

   - If it was expected, declare it in the `expected` attribute of the `Test` annotation. Or, if further checks should be done on the exception object itself, catch it and ignore it. (In this case, there must be also a call to `Assert.fail` at the end of the `try` block, to indicate that the expected exception was not produced).
   - If it was not expected, catch it and execute Assert.fail. (A previous call to `Exception.printStackTrace` is also useful).
2. If the exception was not originated into the tested code or it is not interesting to the test (for example, most of the IOExceptions are produced at network level, before the test could *even be completed*), rethrow it at the `throws` clause.

Why you should expect an exception in the tester? Remind: You should code *one test method for every possible result on the tested code* (in order to achieve a high code coverage): In your case, one method that must return successfully, and at least another one that must produce an Exception.

Answer (score 2):

Three points about JUnit:

- Tests should be precise, they should pass or fail unambiguously based solely on how the test inputs are set up.
- Tests should have failures reported back into the framework.
- Tests should not rely on having their output read.

Your example fails on all three counts. If an exception gets thrown or not, the test still passes. If an exception is thrown JUnit never finds out about it and can't include it in the test results. The only way to know something went wrong is to read what the test writes to stdout, which makes errors too easy to ignore. This is not a useful way to write tests.

JUnit was designed to make doing the right thing easy and to give developers useful feedback. If an exception gets thrown from a test method, it gets caught by the framework. If the test was annotated with an exception indicating that exception is expected, then the framework marks the test as passing. Otherwise the framework fails the test and records the stacktrace for reporting. The framework reports what assertions fail and what unexpected exceptions occurred so that everybody knows if the tests worked or not.

If you expect a test to succeed without throwing an exception, then if anything in the test can throw a checked exception, add `throws Exception` to the test method signature. Adding the `throws` to the signature doesn't say the method *has to* throw anything, it just lets any exceptions that happen to occur get thrown so that the test framework can catch them.

The only instance where you would actually catch the exception in the test is where you want to test assertions about the exception; for instance, you could test that the message on the exception is what you expect, or if the exception has a cause set on it. In that case you would add `Assert.fail()` at the end of the try-block so that not having an exception thrown will cause the test to fail.

**It isn’t having a try-catch block that is so bad, it’s the absence of anything  that will cause the test to fail that is bad.**

When you write a test at first, make it fail. That way you prove to yourself that you know what the test is doing, and you confirm that, when there is a failure, you will be made aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of exception is it? Is it

1. an exception from doing something like using streams that won't happen in your unit test or
2. an exception that can happen because of some kind of bad input?

If it's 1. I would just put it at the method signature level because a try-catch is serving no real purpose other than ceremony.

```
@Test
public void testFoo() throws Exception {
    // ...
}
```

If it's 2. it becomes a little more complicated. You need to ask yourself what should be happening if the Exception is thrown. Should the test fail? Is it expected? Is it irrelevant? Examples below of how to handle all of these. **BEWARE:** I only used Exception because you did. I hope it really isn't though because if it's possible for some *other* exception to be thrown other than the expected then these will be very wonky. If possible don't use `Exception`, use something more specific (in the junit *and* code).

```
// The below code assumes you've imported the org.junit.Assert class.

@Test
public void thisShouldFailIfExceptionCaught() {
    //Given...
    try {
        // When...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
    // Then...
}

@Test
public void thisShouldPassOnlyIfTheExceptionIsCaught() {
    //Given...
    try {
        // When...
        Assert.fail();
    } catch (Exception expected) {}
    // No "then" needed, the fact that it didn't fail is enough.
}

@Test
public void irrelevantExceptionThatCouldBeThrown() {
    //Given...
    try {
        // When...
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    // Then...
}
```

Comment: It depends on the method I'm using. It could be either a `JMSException`, `IOException` or `ConfigurationException` :) Thank you for your enlightening answer!

Comment: @Nelsch no problem! I would suggest in the future that when asking questions to not use `Exception` unless you really mean it (testing something that `throws Exception` for example), even names like `SomeCheckedException` or `SomeUncheckedException` really explain the issue at hand.

Comment: Unit tests should not catch exceptions just to call `fail()`. In fact, it's totally fine for all unit tests to declare `Exception` since the test method is (should!) never called from anywhere except the test framework. And the latter just lets the test fail in case of an exception which is exactly what you want.