# Junit for try catch

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to add a unit test case which involves this code:

```
try(InputStream zippedInputStream = attachmentReader.getPayloadStream(dP)){
  <some code>
 } catch(Exception t) {
            Throwables.propagate(t);
 }
```

Please help me in writing a mockito for this.

Comment: Maybe meet your issue
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423643/try-catch-in-a-junit-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423643/try-catch-in-a-junit-test)

Answer (score 0):

Your production code does:

- fetch a stream from a reader
- throw a runtime exception

So for your test, you will need

- a mocked `attachmentReader` thing (which gets passed to your production code)
- that mock is configured to return an InputStream
- and in turn, that stream is configured so that the production code does  certain things

From there: you write at least two tests, one for the good path; and one where you configure your stream to throw - so that you can put up  `@Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)` .