# What is the best approach to unit test try catch to throw an exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```java
final GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
final XMLGregorianCalendar dt;
try {
    dt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
} return dt;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try catch in a JUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423643/try-catch-in-a-junit-test)

Comment: Please provide additional explanation what you want to achieve (not only a piece of code).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Junit4 libraries to test the `IllegalArgumentException.class` exception as below assuming your method signature is `XMLGregorianCalendar getCalendar()`

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void whenExceptionThrown_thenExpectationSatisfied() {
    getCalendar();
}

XMLGregorianCalendar getCalendar() {
        final GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        final XMLGregorianCalendar dt;
        try {
            dt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

For Junit 5

```
@Test
void testGetCalendar() {
  Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
    getCalendar();
  });

}
```

Comment: does expected work for Junit5? as it would be amazing to use 5.

Comment: yes updated my ans with Junit5 test code  @MoonMaker

Comment: Read this doc (https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/expected-exception-example/) and got the same answer , but is complaining about  org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown:

Comment: @Test
    public void whenExceptionThrown_thenExpectationSatisfied() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            service.getDateAndTime();
        });
    }

Comment: your test method is expect an error but getCalendar will never throw an error so you have got the exception